# Making a function which can be called with an object literal

Tags: javascript

I am working on a code snippet to make a function which can be called with an object literal.

Problem area: If I do not need to track the product value, then a check has been placed for undefined. But do I really need to make check for each and every value if it's not there in the object literal?

```
trackProduct = function (args) {

      if(args.label == undefined) {
        value.push([args.category, args.action, args.value]);
      } else if(args.value == undefined){
        value.push([args.category, args.action, args.label]);
      } else {
        value.push([args.category, args.action, args.label, args.value]);
      }
};
```

I'm calling this function via below object literal. I have not passed the value parameter.

```
trackProduct({
    category: elemcategory,
    action: elemaction,
    label: elemlabel
});
```

Do we need to check for undefined for all three parameters? Any suggestions on how to improve this code?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: You are using array to store different things, that doesn't make sense. You should just `value.push( args )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just a note: You check against `undefined`, but `undefined` is unfortunately *not* a keyword, meaning it's mutable. Better to use `typeof something === 'undefined'`

If I understand you right, you want to be able to "leave out" anyone of the object values. In that case, here's my take on the code (I'm returning an array, just for clarity)

```
function trackProduct(obj) {
  var keys = ['category', 'action', 'label', 'value'],  // properties to look for
      values = [],
      i, l, value;

  for(i = 0, l = keys.length ; i < l ; i++) {
    value = obj[keys[i]];
    if(typeof value !== 'undefined') {
      values.push(value); // if the value's there, put it in the array
    }
  }

  return values;
}
```

This would work like so:

```
trackProduct({
  category: "foo",
  label:    "bar",
  value:    "23",
  ignored:  "something"
}); // => ["foo", "bar", "23"]
```

Comment: Not referencing the builtin `undefined` variable because it's mutable is equivalent of not calling any of the builtin functions (like `Array.push()`) because these too are mutable.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo I see your point, but I stand by mine. The point is that `undefined` _isn't_ a built-in variable in some runtimes. Saying `x === undefined` only works in those cases precisely because the variable doesn't exist at all, and thus it's not defined (neither natively or in the code being run). In those cases, the ability to define it only spells trouble; you can't (re)define it without making it, well, defined. Conversely you can redefine `Array.prototype.push` in limitless ways without necessarily breaking it.

Comment: Maybe you could point out some examples of the runtimes where `undefined` variable is missing, because frankly, I don't know any.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo I'm not about to update an old answer when it's still perfectly valid. [But look at this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript) and the one below it which argues your case. _In effect_, the `undefined` variable is missing in _all_ runtimes - that's the point. That's what makes it "not defined". The difference is whether the variable name `undefined` is _writable_ or not. In modern browsers (ECMAScript 5), it isn't, but in older ones it is. See also [MDN](http://mzl.la/SsajwO)

Comment: No, the `undefined` variable is actually defined, just that it's value is `undefined`. It's confusing, but you can easily test it by calling `window.hasOwnProperty('undefined')`. You can also easily declare your own undefined variable by simply declaring `var undefined;` in local scope.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo Ok, yes, it's defined as being not defined, and yes, confusing. Also irrelevant. If the name's writable, there's no difference between saying `x === undefined` and `x === someRandomVarThatDoesntExist`. I prefer using `typeof x === 'undefined'` over that.

Comment: No, no. There is a major difference - the latter one doesn't work. If I do `x === someRandomVarThatDoesntExist` I'll get an error because I'm attempting to reference a not existing variable. I however I compare `x === undefined` it will work because variable `undefined` is defined, but hasn't been assigned a value, so it's value is `undefined`.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo You're right, my mistake. I was thinking of function arguments that are declared by not passed (no ref error, but still undefined).